# trouble with OOP functions - javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm developing a datepicker using pure javascript. The datepicker works fine, but i have a problem that i dont know how to solve:

I have this line:

```
var my_cal = new Calendar("cal","2020-01-1","2022-01-01","2021-06-14");
```

that declare the Calendar object. Among the variables of the object, there are 2 variables whose value is the picked dates:

```
this.FromDate=null;
this.ToDate=null;
```

Also,there is a function that executes when the user clicks on one of the dates in the calendar, and the function according to the conditions, defines the two variables I mentioned above.

```
   this.date_pick=function()
   {
     if(my_cal.FromDate==null){
       my_cal.FromDate=new Date(this.getAttribute("data-date"));
       console.log("From Date "+my_cal.FromDate);
     }
     else {
       if(my_cal.ToDate==null){
          let todate=new Date(this.getAttribute("data-date"));
          if(todate>my_cal.FromDate){
            my_cal.ToDate=new Date(this.getAttribute("data-date"));
            console.log("To Date "+my_cal.ToDate);
          }
       }
       else {
         my_cal.FromDate=new Date(this.getAttribute("data-date"));
         console.log("From Date "+my_cal.FromDate);
         my_cal.ToDate=null;
       }
     }

      my_cal.create();
   };
```

The problem is that I need to call directly to the `my_cal` variable to make the function work, and I want it to work for each calendar individually created by the page.

I tried to change the `my_cal.` to `this.`, like that:

```
   this.date_pick=function()
   {
     if(this.FromDate==null){
       this.FromDate=new Date(this.getAttribute("data-date"));
       console.log("From Date "+this.FromDate);
     }
     else {
       if(this.ToDate==null){
          let todate=new Date(this.getAttribute("data-date"));
          if(todate>this.FromDate){
            this.ToDate=new Date(this.getAttribute("data-date"));
            console.log("To Date "+this.ToDate);
          }
       }
       else {
         this.FromDate=new Date(this.getAttribute("data-date"));
         console.log("From Date "+this.FromDate);
         this.ToDate=null;
       }
     }

      this.create();
   };
```

but I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.create is not a function
    at HTMLTableCellElement.Calendar.date_pick
```

and I really dont know what to do.

codepen for the whole project: https://codepen.io/DavidiAllove/pen/YzZMgGg

Thanks for the helpers !! :)

EDIT:
I changed the `self` to `this`, I get the same error.

Comment: `self` is not the same as `this`

Comment: Please show us how you are calling `my_call.date_pick()`

Comment: hey, all the `<td>` elements contain the dates, and the class of the elements is `date_click`. onclick the `<td>`, the app call the function `date_pick()`.
`var items = document.getElementsByClassName('date_click');
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
items[i].addEventListener('click', this.date_pick);
    }`